# Expose element of parent component to child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a main component that handles the toolbar and sidnav of my angular application.  I would like to make a div inside the toolbar available to child components (and controllers) to customize so that they can do things like change the toolbar title text and add contextual buttons.  This feels sort of like the opposite of transposition where a parent component can customize part of a child component (e.g. a menu component customizing the content of a button).  One option would be to have the toolbar managed by a service, but even then I can't think of a great way to customize the content of the toolbar without doing a decent amount of javascript that builds up dom elements (one of the things I always try to avoid in angular).

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 1.6.x [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) use isolate scope only:

> Components only control their own View and Data: Components should
>   never modify any data or DOM that is out of their own scope. Normally,
>   in AngularJS it is possible to modify data anywhere in the application
>   through scope inheritance and watches. This is practical, but can also
>   lead to problems when it is not clear which part of the application is
>   responsible for modifying the data. That is why component directives
>   use an isolate scope, so a whole class of scope manipulation is not
>   possible.

So, to make this work you would need to use a directive instead of a component. The div you want to include would need to be a directive itself to be able to alter the parent scope of the toolbar directive. What you would be doing is transcluding one directive inside another, and using shared scope to alter the parent scope.

This article is a really good resource for what you are trying to accomplish. I would start here: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/transclusion-template-scope-in-angular-directives

I have altered the example Codepen from that article to show you how it might work: http://codepen.io/jdoyle/pen/aJQpYo

If you select items in the list you can see that the header name changes to whatever is selected.

```
angular.module("ot-components", [])

.controller("AppController",($scope)=> {
  //Normally, this data would be wrapped in a service. For example only.
  $scope.header = "Marketing";
  $scope.areas = {
    list: [
      "Floorplan",
      "Combinations",
      "Schedule",
      "Publish"
    ],
    current: "Floorplan"
  };
})

.directive("otList", ()=> {
  return {
    scope: false,  // this is one of the major changes
    template: 
    `<ul class="ot-list">
      <li class="ot-list--item"
        ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-bind="item"
        ng-class="{'ot-selected': item === selected}"
        ng-click="selectItem(item)">
       </li>
    </ul>`,
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) => {
      scope.items = JSON.parse(attrs.items);
      scope.selected = attrs.selected;

      scope.selectItem = (item) => {
        scope.selected = item;
        scope.$parent.header = item;  // this is the other major change
      };
    }
  };
})

.directive("otSite", ()=> {
  return {
    scope: true,  // another major change
    transclude: true,
    template: 
    `<div class="ot-site">
        <div class="ot-site--head">
          <img class="ot-site--logo" src="//guestcenter.opentable.com/Content/img/icons/icon/2x/ot-logo-2x.png">
        <h1>{{header}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="ot-site--menu">
        </div>
        <div class="ot-site--body" ng-transclude>
        </div>
        <div class="ot-site--foot">
          &copy; 2015 OpenTable, Inc.
        </div>
      </div>`     
  };
});
```